# AWS SAM lambda container: when specifying resolve-image-repos, what should ImageUri be?

Tags: aws-sam

I'm trying to deploy a docker image as a lambda function via AWS SAM. My SAM template looks something like:

```
Resources:
  StrapiFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      Events:
        Strapi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
    Metadata:
      DockerTag: latest
      DockerContext: ./
      Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Which I'm then trying to deploy (via a CI script) with:

```
sam deploy  \
    --resolve-s3 \
    --resolve-image-repos \
    --region ${AWS_REGION} \
    --template-file ${SAM_FILE} \
    --stack-name my-cms-${STAGE}-stack \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html), `--resolve-image-repos` tells SAM to *"Automatically create Amazon ECR repositories to use for packaging and deploying for non-guided deployments"*.

If I try to deploy this, I get an error:

> Unable to upload artifact None referenced by ImageUri parameter

But if the repository is being created by SAM, I don't know its URI in advance. And from what I can see, it changes each time the deploy is run.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ImageUri in advance, AWS will use it for the creation of the actual repo.

```
  PreProcessorStagingFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageUri: !Sub "preprocessorstaging:${DWHBranch}"
```

In my case AWS SAM creates a repo where the Uri is

Don't know if this was your issue but you can declare the ImageUri before hand.

Comment: Don't know why the Uri did not get posted. Here it is anyway ############.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/projectx6a65646c/preprocessorstagingfunction6b0b99e3repo